# Microprocessor schematic symbol

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, camera, microphone

When drawing a circuit a resistor looks like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aResistors_in_parallel.svg). How would a Microprocessor look? Microphone? Webcam?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_symbol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mic-IEC-Symbol.svg http://www.talkingelectronics.com/CctSymbols/Circuit_Symbols.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microprocessors and webcams (usually) do not have a dedicated symbol. There are basically rectangles with pins attached to them, [like latches](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_5/chpt_9/17.html). A symbol for a microphone can be found [here](http://library.thinkquest.org/10784/circuit_symbols.html).

Answer (score 3):

There's not a schematic symbol for a webcam because it's not an electronic component, it's an end user product. There's not a schematic symbol for a laptop either.

Many components don't have a unique symbol, it already starts with resistors, but there are several symbols for a microphone too:

[image][image]

The right one sometimes has its connections at top and bottom.

Microprocessors and microcontrollers are represented by a rectangle as a container; there's simply too much inside to use separate symbols for all functions. Microcontrollers with not too many pins have their connections usually at left and right, larger controllers will also use top and bottom for the pins. But don't make silly symbols like this one:

[image]

Making it narrower won't save space. Just make it square or rectangular. This is the symbol like it's often made: mimicking the physical package (here even including the bevel indicating pin 1). There's no need for that, you can regroup pins any way you want.